# OSX Mavericks Finder Bug Confuses Files for Tags in a Search

Tags: tags, finder, osx-mavericks

When I search in Finder I'm getting some weird behaviour.

Search results seem to confuse files for Tags. So my entire search is a list of bullets with the filenames confused for 'tag' names INSTEAD of a list of files with the associated app.

For example search on pdf would show the result myFile.pdf as a tag name.

The result is that my search yields the right results but I can't click on the files - so I just end up knowing I have some matching results but no idea where to find them which somewhat defeats the purpose.

Relaunch of Finder doesn't make any difference.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: This might be better suited for superuser.com or apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with finder and I solved it by going to view, then view options then choosing sort by kind.

not sure why this fixed my problem but it did.
hope it works .